# Aurebesh sources

Tags: star-wars

It didn't take me long to learn Aurebesh; I can read at a very slow but steady pace. But I find it surprising that there are no sources of texts written in the script! I searched extensively, but I get swamped with decoders and small samples. The best results are screenshots of *The Mandalorian* or other shows. That is not enough to practice fluent reading.

Are there any short stories or other extended texts, rendered in aurebesh?

Comment: If you have an e-reader that supports font ligatures you can make every book you read written in aurebesh by installing the font

Answer (score 4):

There are no authorised texts written entirely in Aurabesh.

That being said, Aurabesh is merely a *substitution cipher* (e.g. the text is actually in English, just with different characters representing the alphabet, numbers and some punctuation), so you can simply download one of the many [Aurabesh fonts](https://www.dafont.com/aurebesh.font) that are available on the internet, tell your e-reader to use that font and now every book you own is in Aurabesh.

[image]